# Leaving out an infinitive clause : No auxillary and auxiliary after to-infinitive clause

Tags: to-infinitive, infinitive-clauses

The definition below is from the book *"Oxford Guide to English Grammar"*

[image]

I can't understand why there is no auxiliary after ***to*** in the example *"I haven't washed up yet, but I'm going **to."***

But why there is an auxiliary after ***to*** in this example *"I haven't done as much work today as I'd like **to have."***

Is that because the first example is split by the word ", but" there?

Then what about this example *"Jane was chosen for the job, although she didn't expect **to be."***

I want to know the grammar rule applied in the above examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave out a lexical verb when it's implicit, but you cannot leave out an auxiliary verb.  The two examples you provide wherein the infinitive has to be written out ("be" and "have") are auxiliaries in those two specific situations:

> "Jane *was* **chosen** for the job, although she didn't expect *to be*
>   (**chosen**). (the main verb is "choose" (past participle: *chosen*);
>   therefore, "to be" is an auxiliary verb.)
>
> "I *have* not **done** as much work today as I'd like *to have*
>   (**done**)." (the main verb is "do" (past participle:
>   *done*); therefore, "to have" is an auxiliary verb.)

But, in your example,

> "I haven't *washed up* yet, but I'm going **to** (*wash up*)."

the main verb is "wash" (past participle: *washed*); therefore, it is **not** an auxiliary verb and, thus, can stand as just **"to"**.

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy New Year to you, too.